# Shadertoy shader not compiling in p5js

Tags: webgl, p5.js

I've been trying to import some nice shadertoy code that I want to use in p5.js.

https://www.shadertoy.com/view/wtGyRz here's the shadertoy code if anyone wants to look at it.

I believe that I've changed everything to the correct format for WEBGL but it keeps on getting a compile error and I'm not entirely sure why. I'm relatively new to WEBGL and using shaders so help would be greatly appreciated.

So here is my super simple js code:

```
let theShader;

function preload(){
  
  theShader = loadShader('shader.vert', 'shader.frag');
}

function setup() {
  createCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight, WEBGL);
  noStroke();
}

function draw() {  
  shader(theShader);

  theShader.setUniform("iResolution", [width, height]);
  theShader.setUniform("iFrame", frameCount);
  theShader.setUniform("iMouse", [mouseX, map(mouseY, 0, height, height, 0)]);
  theShader.setUniform("iTime", millis()/1000);

  rect(0,0,width, height);
}

function windowResized(){
  resizeCanvas(windowWidth, windowHeight);
}
```

and my vertex shader:

```
attribute vec3 aPosition;

attribute vec2 aTexCoord;

void main() {

  vec4 positionVec4 = vec4(aPosition, 1.0);
  positionVec4.xy = positionVec4.xy * 2.0 - 1.0;

  gl_Position = positionVec4;
}
```

and finally the point of error, my frag shader

```
#ifdef GL_ES
precision mediump float;
#endif
  
#define width 800.f
#define height 450.f
#define numColors 10
#define numCircles 100

uniform vec2 iResolution;
uniform int iFrame;
uniform vec2 iMouse;
uniform float iTime;


vec3 GetColor(vec2 coord, vec4 circles[numCircles], vec3 colors[numColors], float timeDelay){
    int value = 0;
    float r;
    float xc;
    float yc;
    float d = sqrt((coord[0] - xc)*(coord[0]-xc)+(coord[1]-yc)*(coord[1]-yc));
    for(int i = 0; i < numCircles; i++)
    {
        xc = circles[i][0];
        yc = circles[i][1];
        r = circles[i][2];
        d = sqrt((coord[0] - xc)*(coord[0]-xc)+(coord[1]-yc)*(coord[1]-yc));
        if(d <= r && iTime >= timeDelay * float(i))
        {
            value+= int(circles[i][3]);
        }
    }
    return colors[value % numColors];
}

void main(){
    float timeDelay = 0.05f;
    float timeFactor = 50.f;
    vec3 colors[numColors] = vec3[numColors](vec3(0.976, 0.254, 0.266),vec3(0.952, 0.447, 0.172),vec3(0.972, 0.588, 0.117),\
    vec3(0.976, 0.517, 0.290),vec3(0.976, 0.780, 0.309),vec3(0.564, 0.745, 0.427),vec3(0.262, 0.666, 0.545),\
    vec3(0.301,0.564,0.556),vec3(0.341,0.458,0.564),vec3(0.152,0.490,0.631));
    float timeInt = 0.f;
    int i = 0;
    float xGap = 1.f/11.f;
    float yGap = 1.f/11.f;
    vec4 circles[numCircles];
    for(float y = height * yGap; y < height; y+= height * yGap)
    {
        for (float x = width * xGap; x < width; x += width * xGap)
        {
            circles[i] = vec4(x, y, iTime * timeFactor - timeFactor * timeDelay * float(i),i+1);
            i++;
        }
    }

  vec3 col = GetColor(gl_FragCoord, circles, colors, timeDelay);
  gl_FragColor = vec4(col,1.0);
}
```

In all honesty I have no idea why it wouldn't compile. to my untrained eye everything looks fine so i think it might be some sort of small syntax that I'm not used to.

Comment: What error does it report when you compile it?

Comment: Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'useProgram' on 'WebGLRenderingContext': parameter 1 is not of type 'WebGLProgram'. (sketch: line 21)
2

Darn! An error occurred compiling the fragment shader:ERROR: 1:1: '' : syntax error

Thats in the p5 console, in the built in js console it gives this as well:

[.WebGL-0x7fc41446de00]GL ERROR :GL_INVALID_VALUE : glShaderSource: Shader source contains invalid characters.

thanks gman

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is the shadertoy shader is a GLSL ES 3.0 shader for WebGL2 but p5.js only supports GLSL ES 1.0 and WebGL1

The incompatibilities include the `\` at the end of a couple of lines which is what generated this error

> glShaderSource: Shader source contains invalid characters

That took a while to find. Firefox gave a better error

> WebGL warning: shaderSource: `source` contains illegal character 0x5c.

Remove the `\` characters and you'll start getting more relevant errors like

> Darn! An error occurred compiling the fragment shader:
> ERROR: 0:33: '%' : integer modulus operator supported in GLSL ES 3.00 and above only
> ERROR: 0:37: '0.05f' : Floating-point suffix unsupported prior to GLSL ES 3.00
> ERROR: 0:37: '0.05f' : syntax error

Remove the `f` suffixes and more version related issue appear

> An error occurred compiling the fragment shader:
> ERROR: 0:33: '%' : integer modulus operator supported in GLSL ES 3.00 and above only
> ERROR: 0:39: '[]' : array constructor supported in GLSL ES 3.00 and above only
> ERROR: 0:39: '[]' : first-class arrays (array initializer) supported in GLSL ES 3.00 and above only
> ERROR: 0:39: '=' : Invalid operation for arrays
> ERROR: 0:39: '=' : cannot convert from 'const array[10] of 3-component vector of float' to 'mediump array[10] of 3-component vector of float'
> ERROR: 0:56: 'GetColor' : no matching overloaded function found
> ERROR: 0:56: '=' : dimension mismatch
> ERROR: 0:56: '=' : cannot convert from 'const mediump float' to 'mediump 3-component vector of float

Comment: Thank you so much @gman, ur an absolute legend.

Comment: i'm struggling to resolve the last 2 errors. I've resolved pretty much all of them with some simple maths for % and making the array non-static because static arrays aren't a thing in glsl 1. The last errors remaining are the last 3 lines after removing the f suffixes.

ERROR: 0:56: 'GetColor' : no matching overloaded function found
ERROR: 0:56: '=' : dimension mismatch
ERROR: 0:56: '=' : cannot convert from 'const mediump float' to 'mediump 3- component vector of float

in all honesty I can't find where it is.

heres my current code: https://editor.p5js.org/sjcobb/sketches/9C34iOFo-

Comment: The issue with `GetColor` is `gl_FragCoord` is a vec3 but `GetColor` takes a vec2 so pass `gl_FragCoord.xy` but after that it's going to get harder. GLSL 1 only allows constant integer based loops.

Comment: ahhh ic... hmmm

i may have to go around this differently then

Comment: If you want help translating that shader from GLSL ES 3.0 to GLSL ES 1.0 should probably ask a new question. I suspect it will require you to get rid of the colors array and the circles array and put those in textures though. You can maybe get some idea of how to move those to textures by looking at [this](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-gpgpu.html)